# Swapping 2 subs-tree algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I having problem writing an algorithm swap 2 subs-tree, I am trying to write everything in pseudo code, I know there is more to add to this code, any idea can help

```
swap(T,u, v):
    x = u.p
    y = v.p
    if( x!=y )
        u.p = y
        v.p = x
```

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by *swapping 2 subs-tree*. Is it swapping left child and right child of a binary tree?

Comment: The pseudocode looks fine to me. What problems are you facing?

Comment: in this case I am only linking the parent nodes in the case they have different parent, meaning the concerning sub trees are different, right ?,
Thank you for your input